# Getting data from database with php

Tags: php

I want to get the data from my database. The page does not change when I upload the file. Where am I wrong?

verifycheck.php

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect ("###", "###", "###");
mysql_select_db ("db_name", $con);


$result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT * FROM db_tablename");


echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>username</th>
<th>email</th>
<th>password</th>
<th>confirm_password</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['confirm_password'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What file do you upload? If your mysql parameters correct and has true column names in table and that table has some values, your code should work.

Comment: I believe that the problem is not in this code, since the OP mentions: `The page does not change when I upload the file`.

Comment: It's simple, the connection variable comes at the end and not at the beginning; unlike `mysqli_`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think that instead of changing the position of the parameter so it will fit `mysql_` , he should leave the position of that parameter and start using `mysqli_` :)

Comment: @OfirBaruch I couldn't agree with you more ;-)

Comment: Use `mysqli_` functions with [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and be done with it. You stand at later being open to SQL injection(s). Plus, just for the record, you can even omit DB connection altogether when using `mysql_` `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_tablename");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `$con,` from the `mysql_query`

As `mysql_query()` expects first parameter to be the SQL Query, not the SQL connection.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_tablename");
```

Answer (score 1):

Connection object should be second parameter and query string should be first parameter.

Try this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_tablename",$con);
```

Instead of

```
$result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT * FROM db_tablename");
```

Mysql function is deprecated and will remove in future go for **Mysqli** or **PDO** for preventing sql injection

Comment: I tried it but the webpage is still not showing the data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check with your connection parameters as localhost,username password, database and also changing the

```
  $result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT * FROM db_tablename"); 
   as 
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_tablename",$con);
```